# Reverse hangman #10?

Tags: word, letters

If you put in a "t" you might go down it.

If you put in a "g" some have looked for many years.

If you put in an "f" you might be describing your grandmother.

You must explain all clues.The answer is in the form:

> _ p p l e

Followed by an explanation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> _ r a i l

If you put in a "t" you might go down it.

> You can go down a trail.

If you put in a "g" some have looked for many years.

> Many have searched for the Holy Grail, but none have found it.

If you put in an "f" you might be describing your grandmother.

> Usually when you become older you become more frail.